# Adding Sub Folders to Content Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add folders/sub-folders/files to the content folder of MVC3 project.  I added some folders with sub folders and files to the Project Directory of Contents Folder in Explorer.  However, when I try to add them in visual studio, it will not let me add the folder and its sub contents, but keeps navigating to the files in those folders.  Why can't I just add the folder, and its sub folders with files.   It only allows adding the individual files to the Contents root folder and does not create the folder structures.  I want to maintain the folder structures in the Visual Studio Project, but can not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in VS2012 and others, make sure that you have the option "Show All Files" selected in your Solution Explorer.  This will show all the content, subfolders and files in your project.

If your using any source control, ensure that you 'right click' on the folders or files you want to add and choose "include in project" from the pop-up menu.

The reverse of this also works to "exclude from project".

I ran into this issue myself, when first getting into VS, and got quite frustrated at adding content through Windows Explorer, but not being able to see that content appear in the Solution Explorer.